# Stack Level Too Deep: retrieving an ID of a List - Gibbon / MailChimp / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, gibbon

What is the proper way to retrieve an id of a list from MailChimp using Gibbon API Wrapper?

Say I want to do something like:

```
list = gibbon.lists.list(filters: "Foo")
gibbon.lists(list.id).members.create(....)
```

`list.id` returns `stack level too deep` because of the nested attributes inside the `gibbon.list`call. What is the correct way to call `list.id` in Gibbon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up storing `list_id` as an environment variable.

This gives me the ability to limit the amount of `MailChimp API` queries as List Ids are now being stored locally.

I also created additional lists for testing user subscription in different environments (e.g. `staging`). Using the same code base I'm simply replacing the list `ENV` value for different environments.